# Proof that scalar multiplication of linear kernel still a kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given we construct from scalar $a_i > 0$, and linear kernel $k_i(x,y) = <x,y>$ the following:

$k(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i k_i(x,y)$

How can I show using the property that kernels can be represented by positive semi-definite matrices, that k is also a kernel? Let's assume n = 2, I would start with:

$xa_1 M_1 y + xa_2 M_2 y \geq 0 = x(a_1 M_1 + a_2 M_2) y \geq 0 $ and by definition $(a_1 M_1 + a_2 M_2)$ is psd.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

The matrix is PSD, however $A_{1,2}<0$ and hence $e_1^TAe_2 <0$.

For real positive semidefinite matrix, to check positive semidefiniteness, we only verify $x^TAx \geq 0$ rather than $x^TAy \geq 0$.

Hence rather than writing $x^Ta_1M_1y$, I would write $x^Ta_1Mx$.

Comment: Ok, but as you know when we apply a kernel, we usually have two inputs which can be different (as in k(x,y) vs. k(y,y)) - what do we do then?

Comment: It is possible to have negative value when we compute $k(x,y)$. Just that when we verify whether a matrix is positive semidefinite, we only check $x^TAx \geq 0$.

Comment: I understand your comment, but then I dont know how to bring the two parts together. Because at least our definition is k is a kernel i.e. $k(x,y) = x^TMy$ for some positive semi-definite M. So now if I have $k_1$ and $k_2$ and want to show that their sum is psd, I must use this definition - what would I do alternatively?

Comment: $x^T(a_1M_1)y + x^T(a_2M_2)y=x^T(a_1M_1+a_2M_2)y$. You just have to remove the $\geq 0$ in your last line.

Comment: But without $\geq 0$ I haven't shown anything...! After all I want to prove that it is still psd, hence this inequality has to hold

Comment: You have show that $K(x,y)=x^T(a_1M_1+a_2M_2)y$, hence the corresponding $M=a_1M_1+a_2M_2$ and we just have to verify that $M$ is positive semidefinite. $x^TMx=x^T(a_1M_1+a_2M_2)x=a_1x^TM_1x+a_2x^TM_2x \geq 0$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!